# Navigation property fixup for unit testing with EntityFramework 6

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-6

After switching to Entity Framework 6, automatic fixup for navigation properties has been removed. This has wreaked havoc in our unit tests, which work under the assumption that setting one side of a relation, will automatically update the other side as well.

Everything works fine when running the code, because the DetectChanges method on DbContext the automatically synchronizes the relationships, but when unit testing I would prefer not having to create a DbContext just to do this synchronizaton.

I found this blog explaining that it's possible to reuse the T4 template with the EntityFramework6, but this doesn't work for Spatial data types, which have moved to a different namespace.

So my solution was to modify the EntityFramework 4 T4 template file, and fix it to work with EntityFramework 6. I have posted this as an answer, but would still like to know if anyone else has a better solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the T4 template file from EntityFramework4 can be used directly for EntityFramework6 also, to generate POCO objects with Relationship fixup. However when using spatial data types, a couple of modifications are necessary:

Replace utility file include with the EF6 utilities. This will import the correct spatial name space (and probably others as well):

```
<#@ include file="EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
```

Now make the EF4 template file work with the EF6 utilities:

Replace the EF4 metadata loader which looks like this (separated :

```
MetadataLoader loader = new MetadataLoader(this);
...
EdmItemCollection ItemCollection = loader.CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile);
```

With this:

```
var textTransform = DynamicTextTransformation.Create(this);
EdmItemCollection ItemCollection = new EdmMetadataLoader(textTransform.Host, textTransform.Errors).CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile) as EdmItemCollection;
```

and add the missing ArgumentNotNull method at the very bottom, just before the final #> tag:

```
public static void ArgumentNotNull<T>(T arg, string name) where T : class
{
    if (arg == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
    }
}
```